# How to check if command had any output (zsh)

Tags: shell-script, zsh, stdout, output, stderr

I want to print a new line after a command if it had any output (I hope that this will make it more readable once my terminal starts scrolling).

I found this:

```bsh
precmd() {
    precmd() {
        print ""
    }
}
```

Which works, but obviously prints line after every command.

And also this:

```bsh
precmd () {                        
    exec 2>&- >&-
    lastline=$(tail -1 ~/.command.out)
    sleep 0.1
    exec > /dev/tty 2>&1
}

preexec() {
    exec > >(tee ~/.command.out&)
}
```

And tried to modify it, but it "breaks" the output (and makes vim un-usable) even w/o my modificatons.

Comment: What's wrong with just prepending a newline to `$PS1`?

Comment: Nothing, it's just ugly when there is no output

Comment: Anything you do to alter the way the command is run will confuse some programs, especially interactive applications. What you could do is remember the screen position of the previous prompt and compare it with the screen position of the current prompt. It's not exactly what you asked for, but close.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' any pointers on how to do it? I did look in to the man page(s) of zsh but I can't find anything usefull

Comment: @user419050 To get the cursor position, you have to read send an escape sequence to the terminal (the `zsh/terminfo` module can help with that) and read the terminal's response (`read` builtin, note that this will clash with typeahead from the user, I don't think there's a way to avoid that). The place to do this is in `precmd`.

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like this you are looking for? This script will run the first argument and if the command outputs anything on stdout it will also print a newline

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $($1 | tee /dev/tty) ]]; then
    echo
fi
```

Comment: This breaks a lot of applications that expect to write to a terminal.